# Why cancancan methods return wrong value in view, but right in controller?

Tags: cancancan

I have in cancancan abilities `can(:manage, User, id: user.id)`

When user opens own profile, then `can? :update, @user` in the UsersController#show returns correctly true, but in the show view it returns false.

Does anyone know what causes this inconsistency?

cancancan 3.1, rails 6.0.3.4

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it.
The problem was I called `can?` on decorator and it doesn't work.
`can? :update, @user.object` works fine.